# Android/Emma coverage.ec output fails to import into EclEmma

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, emma

I have successfully managed to get ant to build using the emma param and thus instrument my application.

All the tests run correctly and the coverage.em and coverage.ec files get created.
It even creates the coverage.html file which is all great.

However I would like to be able to import the coverage.ec file into the eclipse plugin EclEmma but I keep getting the following error.

> Error while reading execution data file. Invalid execution data file.

Im using Emma 2.0.5312, EclEmma 2.0.1 and Eclipse Indigo.
I have tried merging the .ec and .em files into a .es session file using the command line

java emma -in covereage.ec -in coverage.em -out coverage.es

but this session file still gives the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

EclEmma 2.x uses JaCoCo as its backend. I'm still working on trying to use EclEmma 1.x with android though.